# J2ME read file byte by byte

Tags: file, java-me, jsr75

I have encountered many site examples and almost all are like this:
 http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/ReadDisplayFile.htm
http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/read-file.shtml
They only show how to read a file from a resource file, not on the file system.
This is my current code:

```
InputStream is;
String path = "file:///root1/photos/a.txt"
try {
     fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path,Connector.READ);
     is = fc.openInputStream();
     int a = is.available();
     char buf = 0;
     String buff = new String();
     while (buf!=-1){
           buf=(char)is.read();
           buff+=buf;                      
     }          
 } catch (IOException ex) {}
```

but it doesn't work, and the infinite loop is created.

`is.available();` (`int a`) returns 0 (Why?) and
`file:///root1/photos/a.txt` exists and contains: `Hi!Hello!`
How can I get this to work?

**EDIT:** I figured it out, `(buf!=-1)` is checking -1 on a `unsigned char` so it is never negative. Stewpid mistake. I just changed it to int and it worked. Sorry for bothering. I hope someone will find this useful if it doesn't get deleted

Comment: for _someone will find this useful_ copy your edit into answer and accept it, [this is a recommended way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2729/165773 "find more details at SO Meta"). With less than 100 reputation, you'll probably have to wait for few hours (8 I think) to post self-answer

Comment: Yea, I wanted to do that, but as you said I have rep<100 so I couldn't. The main thing is that it works, that was my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you try this

```
InputStream is;
String path = "file:///root1/photos/a.txt"
try {
     fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path,Connector.READ);
     is = fc.openInputStream();
     int a = is.available();
     char buf = 0;
     StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
     int i=0;     
     String temp1=null;byte bt[]=null;   
     while ((i=is.read())!=-1){
           bt=new byte[1];
           bt[0]=(byte)i;
           temp1=new String(bt);
           buf.append(temp1);
           temp1=null;
           bt=null;

     }          
 } catch (IOException ex) {}
```

buf is string buffer which have the string.